# Will stock options continue to vest if an employee goes into State Disability Insurance (SDI)?

Tags: united-states, california, employee-stock-options, vesting, disability

If an employee in a publicly traded company needs to go on SDI (to get treatment) will the employee continue to vest options (ISOs, RSUs)? Is SDI like a sabbatical from a company's perspective where they don't have to pay salary to the employee but the employee is still on the payroll (or in employment)?

This question is for California, USA but if applicable in other states too, it would be good to know.

Comment: Have you checked with the company? When somebody goes into a status where the pay isn't being paid by the company specific things happen regarding benefits. Some are paid by the company. Some aren't. What is covered by depend on the laws of that state.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep - still in the discovery phase. Asked around but as I am figuring it out I was hoping someone may have an answer or some pointers already. :) Plus, even though there is nothing wrong with the question, some questions feel odd to ask the company :(

Comment: The employee handbook should explain some of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal experience, there are 2 options.

1. Family and Medical Leave (FMLA)
2. SDI

Before taking up SDI it is worth looking into the company's FMLA policy.

But while you are off work under either of these, you would still be on company payroll. So, you'd be continuing to vest the stock options.